# PHP solution for retrieving list of ciphers from server

Tags: php

Does anyone know how I can go about using a pure php solution for retrieving a list of ciphers supported by a remote server?

This is the code to test again a local client (web browser)

```
$ciphers = openssl_get_cipher_methods();

foreach($ciphers as $cipher) {
    echo "{$cipher}<br>";
}
```

**Here is what I need to do**

1. I think what I need to do is create a socket connection to a remote
   connection
2. I need to use a loop to connect with a different cipher each time.
3. For each connection that is successfully established, it should print the name of the cipher we connected with.

Here is some code to establish a secure connection but need help to factor in the above requirements.

```
$url = $_REQUEST['host'];


$ssloptions = array(
    "capture_peer_cert" => false, 
    "allow_self_signed"=>false, 
    "CN_match"=>$url, 
    "verify_peer"=>false, 
    "SNI_enabled"=>true,
    "SNI_server_name"=>$url,
);

$ctx = stream_context_create( array("ssl" => $ssloptions) );
$result = stream_socket_client("ssl://$url:443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
$cont = stream_context_get_params($result);
```

Here is a list of some ciphers we can use to connect with:

TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5

TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA

TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add this to my socket array:

`'ciphers' => $value,`

I also created an array with all the ciphersuites and put it through a `foreach ($ciphersuites_to_test as $value)` to cycle through all the ciphers.