# Test ciphers on a server in php

Tags: php, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to establish that a server supports cipher given. For the moment, i do this, but i dont know how to get the response to know which supports.

This function is to get all the ciphers by level (HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW) and try to know if the server support it.

```
function getCiphers($ip, $level) {
$ciphers = exec("openssl ciphers '" . $level . "'");
$ciphers = explode(":", $ciphers);
$cipherAllow = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($ciphers); $i++) {
    $support = exec("echo -n | openssl s_client -connect " . $ip . ":443 -cipher " . $ciphers[$i] . ' 2>&1');
    usleep(50);
    if ($support === 'DONE')
        $ciphersAllow[] = $ciphers[$i];
}
return $ciphersAllow;
```

}

Also, i see this question ([PHP solution for retrieving list of ciphers from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965225/php-solution-for-retrieving-list-of-ciphers-from-server)), but i dont go correctly.